# Faster Kernel debugging for Windows

Tags: debugging, windbg, kernel-mode

I am Kernel debugging in Windbg and it's slow , very slow stepping through.

My current setup is using VMWARE and Windbg through a com port on the Virtual Machine.

Is there a faster way to debug the Windows Kernel?

What are some of my options?

Comment: Check out ["Slow kernel dbg with VirtualBox and WinDBG"](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16209/slow-kernel-dbg-with-virtualbox-and-windbg/16213) and ["Advice about first steps on reversing windows kernel"](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16209/slow-kernel-dbg-with-virtualbox-and-windbg/16213), you may find your answer there.

Comment: Thanks for linking this. I looked for an answer but I guess I didn't use the magic keywords )

Comment: I didn't used Vmware but, I'm using Hyper-V and serial ports for debugging Windows 7 32-bit. It is fast for me.

Comment: @de6f I'd like to test this because I want to test drivers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want VirtualKd. It is excellent and robust.

http://virtualkd.sysprogs.org

Comment: I will test this out today. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Tested it . This is indeed a lot more faster.

Comment: For some reason it took forever to get it to connect, it seems fine now though. Ironically this tool requires driver signing to be disabled  which is exactly what I am testing. So I am not sure if this is the best tool for what I need but , you did answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

[GynvaelColdwind](https://www.youtube.com/user/GynvaelEN/videos) had invited [honorary_bot](https://twitter.com/honorary_bot) who had 4 streams about Kernel Debugging.

The videos can be found here: [Stream 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s5gOW-N9AAo), [Stream 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Xo_FAx6P0A), [Stream 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zTtVYjjquA), [Stream 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhsH-snYkIc).

Around 34 min in the stream 1 he mentions the slowness of COM connection and around 38 he mentions usage of [VirtualKd](http://virtualkd.sysprogs.org/) and why it works much faster. There's also a short installation/setup process.

Also there are some downsides of this one - as you need to install something on the machine (someone might don't want to do it). So what it's presented as the best solution (for him) is using physical Firewire but the setup requires separate machines.

I recommend to have a watch of those 4 streams if you are new into the topic.

Comment: These are both superb answers that it's hard to pick just one.

Comment: @ApertureSecurity No worries :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are debugging a newer version of Windows (Windows 8 or higher I believe). You should checkout network based debugging. Works like a charm. No third party dependencies.

Just open up a cmd prompt as admin and type:

`bcdedit /debug on
bcdedit /dbgsettings net hostip:w.x.y.z port:n`

Checkout the [MSDN docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-a-network-debugging-connection) for more info